# List contour plot with peaks

Tags: plotting

I have this table that i imported this way

```
data = Import["C:\\nivel\\data.dat", "Table"]
xy = data[[All, {1, 2, 3}]]
```

And i wanted to make a list contour plot of it but got stuck in this:

```
ListContourPlot[xy, PlotTheme -> "Web", ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow", PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

This happens because over the red line the function values are much higher than the rest so i tried to get more definition in the blue part by using 2500 Contours, which apparently wasn´t the answer. I was trying to plot something like this:

[image]

I can´t find the way to show sort of information of the variations over the blue part which can be seen here, where the Plot Range wasn´t used but got that white line instead

[image]

Here is data.dat:

````
{{0., 0.29, 2.60318}, {0.01, 0.29, 2.59941}, {0.02, 0.29,2.60518}, {0.03, 0.29, 2.59939}, {0.04, 0.29, 2.59648}, {0.05, 0.29,
   2.5914}, {0.06, 0.29, 2.60146}, {0.07, 0.29, 2.59771}, {0.08, 0.29,
   2.60201}, {0.09, 0.29, 2.60251}, {0.1, 0.29, 2.60216}, {0.11, 0.29,
   2.59641}, {0.12, 0.29, 2.60149}, {0.13, 0.29, 2.59582}, {0.14, 
  0.29, 2.59847}, {0.15, 0.29, 2.59748}, {0.16, 0.29, 2.59818}, {0.17,
   0.29, 2.60412}, {0.18, 0.29, 2.60794}, {0.19, 0.29, 2.5999}, {0.2, 
  0.29, 2.6069}, {0.21, 0.29, 2.59348}, {0.22, 0.29, 2.60437}, {0.23, 
  0.29, 2.59936}, {0.24, 0.29, 2.60221}, {0.25, 0.29, 2.60119}, {0.26,
   0.29, 2.59254}, {0.27, 0.29, 2.60465}, {0.28, 0.29, 
  2.59631}, {0.29, 0.29, 5.01118}, {0.3, 0.29, 2.60144}, {0.31, 0.29, 
  2.59402}, {0.32, 0.29, 2.59897}, {0.33, 0.29, 2.60085}, {0.34, 0.29,
   2.59941}, {0.35, 0.29, 2.60201}, {0.36, 0.29, 2.60571}, {0.37, 
  0.29, 2.58688}, {0.38, 0.29, 2.60236}, {0., 0.28, 2.59328}, {0.01, 
  0.28, 2.59922}, {0.02, 0.28, 2.6022}, {0.03, 0.28, 2.59704}, {0.04, 
  0.28, 2.59553}, {0.05, 0.28, 2.60662}, {0.06, 0.28, 2.5972}, {0.07, 
  0.28, 2.59171}, {0.08, 0.28, 2.599}, {0.09, 0.28, 2.6026}, {0.1, 
  0.28, 2.60114}, {0.11, 0.28, 2.60028}, {0.12, 0.28, 2.59751}, {0.13,
   0.28, 2.59733}, {0.14, 0.28, 2.59603}, {0.15, 0.28, 
  2.59674}, {0.16, 0.28, 2.59895}, {0.17, 0.28, 2.60182}, {0.18, 0.28,
   2.59797}, {0.19, 0.28, 2.60425}, {0.2, 0.28, 2.60171}, {0.21, 0.28,
   2.60587}, {0.22, 0.28, 2.60025}, {0.23, 0.28, 2.60164}, {0.24, 
  0.28, 2.5953}, {0.25, 0.28, 2.59607}, {0.26, 0.28, 2.59719}, {0.27, 
  0.28, 2.60113}, {0.28, 0.28, 4.98568}, {0.29, 0.28, 2.59253}, {0.3, 
  0.28, 2.59614}, {0.31, 0.28, 2.60804}, {0.32, 0.28, 2.60173}, {0.33,
   0.28, 2.60288}, {0.34, 0.28, 2.60287}, {0.35, 0.28, 
  2.59908}, {0.36, 0.28, 2.59636}, {0.37, 0.28, 2.60145}, {0.38, 0.28,
   2.60448}, {0., 0.27, 2.59881}, {0.01, 0.27, 2.59711}, {0.02, 0.27, 
  2.59678}, {0.03, 0.27, 2.60631}, {0.04, 0.27, 2.60209}, {0.05, 0.27,
   2.6035}, {0.06, 0.27, 2.6039}, {0.07, 0.27, 2.59691}, {0.08, 0.27, 
  2.59859}, {0.09, 0.27, 2.60294}, {0.1, 0.27, 2.60147}, {0.11, 0.27, 
  2.59646}, {0.12, 0.27, 2.60019}, {0.13, 0.27, 2.59796}, {0.14, 0.27,
   2.60493}, {0.15, 0.27, 2.6058}, {0.16, 0.27, 2.59785}, {0.17, 0.27,
   2.6066}, {0.18, 0.27, 2.59799}, {0.19, 0.27, 2.59422}, {0.2, 0.27, 
  2.599}, {0.21, 0.27, 2.60013}, {0.22, 0.27, 2.59835}, {0.23, 0.27, 
  2.60005}, {0.24, 0.27, 2.59305}, {0.25, 0.27, 2.59222}, {0.26, 0.27,
   2.60101}, {0.27, 0.27, 4.99169}, {0.28, 0.27, 2.59761}, {0.29, 
  0.27, 2.60372}, {0.3, 0.27, 2.59417}, {0.31, 0.27, 2.60093}, {0.32, 
  0.27, 2.60208}, {0.33, 0.27, 2.59133}, {0.34, 0.27, 2.60238}, {0.35,
   0.27, 2.59931}, {0.36, 0.27, 2.60012}, {0.37, 0.27, 
  2.59704}, {0.38, 0.27, 2.60396}, {0., 0.26, 2.595}, {0.01, 0.26, 
  2.60003}, {0.02, 0.26, 2.60805}, {0.03, 0.26, 2.59659}, {0.04, 0.26,
   2.60511}, {0.05, 0.26, 2.59537}, {0.06, 0.26, 2.60374}, {0.07, 
  0.26, 2.6}, {0.08, 0.26, 2.5926}, {0.09, 0.26, 2.59906}, {0.1, 0.26,
   2.59752}, {0.11, 0.26, 2.5961}, {0.12, 0.26, 2.60426}, {0.13, 0.26,
   2.59719}, {0.14, 0.26, 2.60646}, {0.15, 0.26, 2.60049}, {0.16, 
  0.26, 2.59499}, {0.17, 0.26, 2.5997}, {0.18, 0.26, 2.59843}, {0.19, 
  0.26, 2.59819}, {0.2, 0.26, 2.59626}, {0.21, 0.26, 2.59395}, {0.22, 
  0.26, 2.5953}, {0.23, 0.26, 2.60236}, {0.24, 0.26, 2.61434}, {0.25, 
  0.26, 2.59995}, {0.26, 0.26, 4.98679}, {0.27, 0.26, 2.59627}, {0.28,
   0.26, 2.60414}, {0.29, 0.26, 2.60296}, {0.3, 0.26, 2.60119}, {0.31,
   0.26, 2.59962}, {0.32, 0.26, 2.59848}, {0.33, 0.26, 
  2.59652}, {0.34, 0.26, 2.59949}, {0.35, 0.26, 2.60036}, {0.36, 0.26,
   2.60527}, {0.37, 0.26, 2.59518}, {0.38, 0.26, 2.59733}, {0., 0.25, 
  2.60272}, {0.01, 0.25, 2.60273}, {0.02, 0.25, 2.59968}, {0.03, 0.25,
   2.6021}, {0.04, 0.25, 2.60016}, {0.05, 0.25, 2.59955}, {0.06, 0.25,
   2.60091}, {0.07, 0.25, 2.59721}, {0.08, 0.25, 2.59956}, {0.09, 
  0.25, 2.6063}, {0.1, 0.25, 2.59443}, {0.11, 0.25, 2.59665}, {0.12, 
  0.25, 2.60077}, {0.13, 0.25, 2.5976}, {0.14, 0.25, 2.60404}, {0.15, 
  0.25, 2.60061}, {0.16, 0.25, 2.60117}, {0.17, 0.25, 2.60074}, {0.18,
   0.25, 2.59866}, {0.19, 0.25, 2.60672}, {0.2, 0.25, 2.59564}, {0.21,
   0.25, 2.59214}, {0.22, 0.25, 2.60344}, {0.23, 0.25, 
  2.60055}, {0.24, 0.25, 2.59672}, {0.25, 0.25, 5.00194}, {0.26, 0.25,
   2.60661}, {0.27, 0.25, 2.60419}, {0.28, 0.25, 2.59905}, {0.29, 
  0.25, 2.60114}, {0.3, 0.25, 2.58599}, {0.31, 0.25, 2.5945}, {0.32, 
  0.25, 2.60187}, {0.33, 0.25, 2.59979}, {0.34, 0.25, 2.59143}, {0.35,
   0.25, 2.60715}, {0.36, 0.25, 2.60231}, {0.37, 0.25, 
  2.59691}, {0.38, 0.25, 2.59103}, {0., 0.24, 2.59714}, {0.01, 0.24, 
  2.59744}, {0.02, 0.24, 2.6025}, {0.03, 0.24, 2.60305}, {0.04, 0.24, 
  2.5985}, {0.05, 0.24, 2.60108}, {0.06, 0.24, 2.59596}, {0.07, 0.24, 
  2.60291}, {0.08, 0.24, 2.60448}, {0.09, 0.24, 2.60581}, {0.1, 0.24, 
  2.60468}, {0.11, 0.24, 2.6069}, {0.12, 0.24, 2.60067}, {0.13, 0.24, 
  2.59795}, {0.14, 0.24, 2.60825}, {0.15, 0.24, 2.59341}, {0.16, 0.24,
   2.59629}, {0.17, 0.24, 2.60062}, {0.18, 0.24, 2.60764}, {0.19, 
  0.24, 2.60312}, {0.2, 0.24, 2.60339}, {0.21, 0.24, 2.59514}, {0.22, 
  0.24, 2.59821}, {0.23, 0.24, 2.5968}, {0.24, 0.24, 4.99489}, {0.25, 
  0.24, 2.60224}, {0.26, 0.24, 2.59923}, {0.27, 0.24, 2.60008}, {0.28,
   0.24, 2.60051}, {0.29, 0.24, 2.6048}, {0.3, 0.24, 2.5992}, {0.31, 
  0.24, 2.60631}, {0.32, 0.24, 2.5969}, {0.33, 0.24, 2.60689}, {0.34, 
  0.24, 2.59606}, {0.35, 0.24, 2.60139}, {0.36, 0.24, 2.59844}, {0.37,
   0.24, 2.59825}, {0.38, 0.24, 2.59943}, {0., 0.23, 2.60467}, {0.01, 
  0.23, 2.6013}, {0.02, 0.23, 2.59971}, {0.03, 0.23, 2.59585}, {0.04, 
  0.23, 2.60467}, {0.05, 0.23, 2.59909}, {0.06, 0.23, 2.59845}, {0.07,
   0.23, 2.5989}, {0.08, 0.23, 2.59938}, {0.09, 0.23, 2.60008}, {0.1, 
  0.23, 2.59675}, {0.11, 0.23, 2.59295}, {0.12, 0.23, 2.60267}, {0.13,
   0.23, 2.60064}, {0.14, 0.23, 2.60154}, {0.15, 0.23, 
  2.60261}, {0.16, 0.23, 2.59675}, {0.17, 0.23, 2.60262}, {0.18, 0.23,
   2.59933}, {0.19, 0.23, 2.60312}, {0.2, 0.23, 2.59926}, {0.21, 0.23,
   2.602}, {0.22, 0.23, 2.60063}, {0.23, 0.23, 5.01542}, {0.24, 0.23, 
  2.59451}, {0.25, 0.23, 2.59594}, {0.26, 0.23, 2.60059}, {0.27, 0.23,
   2.59995}, {0.28, 0.23, 2.60509}, {0.29, 0.23, 2.59718}, {0.3, 0.23,
   2.60212}, {0.31, 0.23, 2.59739}, {0.32, 0.23, 2.59365}, {0.33, 
  0.23, 2.59865}, {0.34, 0.23, 2.59735}, {0.35, 0.23, 2.60009}, {0.36,
   0.23, 2.60498}, {0.37, 0.23, 2.60003}, {0.38, 0.23, 2.59919}, {0., 
  0.22, 2.60177}, {0.01, 0.22, 2.59752}, {0.02, 0.22, 2.60038}, {0.03,
   0.22, 2.59582}, {0.04, 0.22, 2.60123}, {0.05, 0.22, 
  2.60361}, {0.06, 0.22, 2.59825}, {0.07, 0.22, 2.6003}, {0.08, 0.22, 
  2.59578}, {0.09, 0.22, 2.60092}, {0.1, 0.22, 2.59832}, {0.11, 0.22, 
  2.59609}, {0.12, 0.22, 2.59981}, {0.13, 0.22, 2.60057}, {0.14, 0.22,
   2.60328}, {0.15, 0.22, 2.60157}, {0.16, 0.22, 2.59762}, {0.17, 
  0.22, 2.60111}, {0.18, 0.22, 2.6066}, {0.19, 0.22, 2.60522}, {0.2, 
  0.22, 2.60683}, {0.21, 0.22, 2.60066}, {0.22, 0.22, 5.0035}, {0.23, 
  0.22, 2.60329}, {0.24, 0.22, 2.59824}, {0.25, 0.22, 2.59628}, {0.26,
   0.22, 2.60564}, {0.27, 0.22, 2.60381}, {0.28, 0.22, 2.601}, {0.29, 
  0.22, 2.60217}, {0.3, 0.22, 2.60962}, {0.31, 0.22, 2.60193}, {0.32, 
  0.22, 2.60035}, {0.33, 0.22, 2.60797}, {0.34, 0.22, 2.60397}, {0.35,
   0.22, 2.59431}, {0.36, 0.22, 2.60055}, {0.37, 0.22, 
  2.60087}, {0.38, 0.22, 2.60354}, {0., 0.21, 2.59707}, {0.01, 0.21, 
  2.59702}, {0.02, 0.21, 2.60249}, {0.03, 0.21, 2.60174}, {0.04, 0.21,
   2.60196}, {0.05, 0.21, 2.60216}, {0.06, 0.21, 2.60494}, {0.07, 
  0.21, 2.59293}, {0.08, 0.21, 2.59679}, {0.09, 0.21, 2.60404}, {0.1, 
  0.21, 2.60285}, {0.11, 0.21, 2.60702}, {0.12, 0.21, 2.59602}, {0.13,
   0.21, 2.59514}, {0.14, 0.21, 2.60233}, {0.15, 0.21, 
  2.60228}, {0.16, 0.21, 2.60096}, {0.17, 0.21, 2.59902}, {0.18, 0.21,
   2.5908}, {0.19, 0.21, 2.5983}, {0.2, 0.21, 2.59429}, {0.21, 0.21, 
  4.9921}, {0.22, 0.21, 2.59946}, {0.23, 0.21, 2.60222}, {0.24, 0.21, 
  2.59484}, {0.25, 0.21, 2.58895}, {0.26, 0.21, 2.60182}, {0.27, 0.21,
   2.59227}, {0.28, 0.21, 2.60145}, {0.29, 0.21, 2.59825}, {0.3, 0.21,
   2.60293}, {0.31, 0.21, 2.60391}, {0.32, 0.21, 2.60084}, {0.33, 
  0.21, 2.60094}, {0.34, 0.21, 2.60177}, {0.35, 0.21, 2.5991}, {0.36, 
  0.21, 2.59507}, {0.37, 0.21, 2.60073}, {0.38, 0.21, 2.60312}, {0., 
  0.2, 2.59869}, {0.01, 0.2, 2.59528}, {0.02, 0.2, 2.59882}, {0.03, 
  0.2, 2.60499}, {0.04, 0.2, 2.60077}, {0.05, 0.2, 2.59726}, {0.06, 
  0.2, 2.60013}, {0.07, 0.2, 2.60477}, {0.08, 0.2, 2.60048}, {0.09, 
  0.2, 2.59725}, {0.1, 0.2, 2.60383}, {0.11, 0.2, 2.60059}, {0.12, 
  0.2, 2.60056}, {0.13, 0.2, 2.60037}, {0.14, 0.2, 2.59556}, {0.15, 
  0.2, 2.59858}, {0.16, 0.2, 2.60076}, {0.17, 0.2, 2.59676}, {0.18, 
  0.2, 2.60841}, {0.19, 0.2, 2.60139}, {0.2, 0.2, 5.00509}, {0.21, 
  0.2, 2.59696}, {0.22, 0.2, 2.60156}, {0.23, 0.2, 2.59494}, {0.24, 
  0.2, 2.59968}, {0.25, 0.2, 2.59671}, {0.26, 0.2, 2.59317}, {0.27, 
  0.2, 2.5954}, {0.28, 0.2, 2.60469}, {0.29, 0.2, 2.59263}, {0.3, 0.2,
   2.60076}, {0.31, 0.2, 2.59991}, {0.32, 0.2, 2.58877}, {0.33, 0.2, 
  2.5998}, {0.34, 0.2, 2.59209}, {0.35, 0.2, 2.59887}, {0.36, 0.2, 
  2.60243}, {0.37, 0.2, 2.59789}, {0.38, 0.2, 2.59499}, {0., 0.19, 
  2.599}, {0.01, 0.19, 2.60179}, {0.02, 0.19, 2.59974}, {0.03, 0.19, 
  2.60091}, {0.04, 0.19, 2.6031}, {0.05, 0.19, 2.59732}, {0.06, 0.19, 
  2.5999}, {0.07, 0.19, 2.59744}, {0.08, 0.19, 2.60319}, {0.09, 0.19, 
  2.60153}, {0.1, 0.19, 2.59611}, {0.11, 0.19, 2.59747}, {0.12, 0.19, 
  2.60003}, {0.13, 0.19, 2.60641}, {0.14, 0.19, 2.60127}, {0.15, 0.19,
   2.59913}, {0.16, 0.19, 2.59445}, {0.17, 0.19, 2.59659}, {0.18, 
  0.19, 2.60084}, {0.19, 0.19, 4.99985}, {0.2, 0.19, 2.59734}, {0.21, 
  0.19, 2.60437}, {0.22, 0.19, 2.5952}, {0.23, 0.19, 2.59913}, {0.24, 
  0.19, 2.59564}, {0.25, 0.19, 2.60117}, {0.26, 0.19, 2.60362}, {0.27,
   0.19, 2.60446}, {0.28, 0.19, 2.595}, {0.29, 0.19, 2.60176}, {0.3, 
  0.19, 2.5986}, {0.31, 0.19, 2.58845}, {0.32, 0.19, 2.60659}, {0.33, 
  0.19, 2.5977}, {0.34, 0.19, 2.59708}, {0.35, 0.19, 2.60218}, {0.36, 
  0.19, 2.60381}, {0.37, 0.19, 2.60509}, {0.38, 0.19, 2.59909}, {0., 
  0.18, 2.60727}, {0.01, 0.18, 2.59317}, {0.02, 0.18, 2.59868}, {0.03,
   0.18, 2.60042}, {0.04, 0.18, 2.5956}, {0.05, 0.18, 2.59817}, {0.06,
   0.18, 2.59631}, {0.07, 0.18, 2.59656}, {0.08, 0.18, 2.5998}, {0.09,
   0.18, 2.59783}, {0.1, 0.18, 2.59695}, {0.11, 0.18, 2.59801}, {0.12,
   0.18, 2.60263}, {0.13, 0.18, 2.6042}, {0.14, 0.18, 2.59639}, {0.15,
   0.18, 2.59852}, {0.16, 0.18, 2.60149}, {0.17, 0.18, 
  2.60407}, {0.18, 0.18, 4.99662}, {0.19, 0.18, 2.6079}, {0.2, 0.18, 
  2.59842}, {0.21, 0.18, 2.60079}, {0.22, 0.18, 2.59963}, {0.23, 0.18,
   2.59736}, {0.24, 0.18, 2.59808}, {0.25, 0.18, 2.59691}, {0.26, 
  0.18, 2.60039}, {0.27, 0.18, 2.5964}, {0.28, 0.18, 2.60057}, {0.29, 
  0.18, 2.60196}, {0.3, 0.18, 2.60293}, {0.31, 0.18, 2.59599}, {0.32, 
  0.18, 2.59535}, {0.33, 0.18, 2.59301}, {0.34, 0.18, 2.59703}, {0.35,
   0.18, 2.60197}, {0.36, 0.18, 2.60082}, {0.37, 0.18, 
  2.60448}, {0.38, 0.18, 2.59796}, {0., 0.17, 2.59622}, {0.01, 0.17, 
  2.59535}, {0.02, 0.17, 2.60031}, {0.03, 0.17, 2.59577}, {0.04, 0.17,
   2.59586}, {0.05, 0.17, 2.59694}, {0.06, 0.17, 2.60352}, {0.07, 
  0.17, 2.59959}, {0.08, 0.17, 2.59729}, {0.09, 0.17, 2.60423}, {0.1, 
  0.17, 2.59962}, {0.11, 0.17, 2.60376}, {0.12, 0.17, 2.60194}, {0.13,
   0.17, 2.59466}, {0.14, 0.17, 2.60376}, {0.15, 0.17, 
  2.60561}, {0.16, 0.17, 2.60482}, {0.17, 0.17, 4.98406}, {0.18, 0.17,
   2.60047}, {0.19, 0.17, 2.59619}, {0.2, 0.17, 2.60517}, {0.21, 0.17,
   2.59239}, {0.22, 0.17, 2.59257}, {0.23, 0.17, 2.60314}, {0.24, 
  0.17, 2.60215}, {0.25, 0.17, 2.59908}, {0.26, 0.17, 2.60359}, {0.27,
   0.17, 2.59973}, {0.28, 0.17, 2.5992}, {0.29, 0.17, 2.6002}, {0.3, 
  0.17, 2.59489}, {0.31, 0.17, 2.5955}, {0.32, 0.17, 2.59833}, {0.33, 
  0.17, 2.60059}, {0.34, 0.17, 2.6006}, {0.35, 0.17, 2.60376}, {0.36, 
  0.17, 2.60773}, {0.37, 0.17, 2.60612}, {0.38, 0.17, 2.60099}, {0., 
  0.16, 2.59691}, {0.01, 0.16, 2.59816}, {0.02, 0.16, 2.60311}, {0.03,
   0.16, 2.60158}, {0.04, 0.16, 2.60463}, {0.05, 0.16, 
  2.60384}, {0.06, 0.16, 2.59592}, {0.07, 0.16, 2.60863}, {0.08, 0.16,
   2.59981}, {0.09, 0.16, 2.60154}, {0.1, 0.16, 2.60327}, {0.11, 0.16,
   2.60279}, {0.12, 0.16, 2.60404}, {0.13, 0.16, 2.59773}, {0.14, 
  0.16, 2.60233}, {0.15, 0.16, 2.59529}, {0.16, 0.16, 4.993}, {0.17, 
  0.16, 2.60722}, {0.18, 0.16, 2.59574}, {0.19, 0.16, 2.60157}, {0.2, 
  0.16, 2.60652}, {0.21, 0.16, 2.60441}, {0.22, 0.16, 2.59114}, {0.23,
   0.16, 2.59477}, {0.24, 0.16, 2.6056}, {0.25, 0.16, 2.60503}, {0.26,
   0.16, 2.59345}, {0.27, 0.16, 2.60058}, {0.28, 0.16, 
  2.60281}, {0.29, 0.16, 2.59734}, {0.3, 0.16, 2.60118}, {0.31, 0.16, 
  2.60271}, {0.32, 0.16, 2.59164}, {0.33, 0.16, 2.6021}, {0.34, 0.16, 
  2.59936}, {0.35, 0.16, 2.60445}, {0.36, 0.16, 2.60088}, {0.37, 0.16,
   2.59568}, {0.38, 0.16, 2.60272}, {0., 0.15, 2.59744}, {0.01, 0.15, 
  2.59522}, {0.02, 0.15, 2.60158}, {0.03, 0.15, 2.59892}, {0.04, 0.15,
   2.59764}, {0.05, 0.15, 2.59712}, {0.06, 0.15, 2.59828}, {0.07, 
  0.15, 2.59906}, {0.08, 0.15, 2.59291}, {0.09, 0.15, 2.60237}, {0.1, 
  0.15, 2.60035}, {0.11, 0.15, 2.59482}, {0.12, 0.15, 2.59388}, {0.13,
   0.15, 2.60257}, {0.14, 0.15, 2.59976}, {0.15, 0.15, 
  4.98779}, {0.16, 0.15, 2.59503}, {0.17, 0.15, 2.59697}, {0.18, 0.15,
   2.59178}, {0.19, 0.15, 2.60307}, {0.2, 0.15, 2.59667}, {0.21, 0.15,
   2.59642}, {0.22, 0.15, 2.59898}, {0.23, 0.15, 2.6014}, {0.24, 0.15,
   2.60407}, {0.25, 0.15, 2.59954}, {0.26, 0.15, 2.60563}, {0.27, 
  0.15, 2.59744}, {0.28, 0.15, 2.59546}, {0.29, 0.15, 2.60305}, {0.3, 
  0.15, 2.60314}, {0.31, 0.15, 2.59863}, {0.32, 0.15, 2.5953}, {0.33, 
  0.15, 2.59439}, {0.34, 0.15, 2.60015}, {0.35, 0.15, 2.60299}, {0.36,
   0.15, 2.60173}, {0.37, 0.15, 2.60439}, {0.38, 0.15, 2.60396}, {0., 
  0.14, 2.5996}, {0.01, 0.14, 2.59652}, {0.02, 0.14, 2.60082}, {0.03, 
  0.14, 2.59965}, {0.04, 0.14, 2.60343}, {0.05, 0.14, 2.60126}, {0.06,
   0.14, 2.6004}, {0.07, 0.14, 2.60726}, {0.08, 0.14, 2.59598}, {0.09,
   0.14, 2.60236}, {0.1, 0.14, 2.60401}, {0.11, 0.14, 2.59747}, {0.12,
   0.14, 2.60041}, {0.13, 0.14, 2.60463}, {0.14, 0.14, 4.9982}, {0.15,
   0.14, 2.60354}, {0.16, 0.14, 2.60981}, {0.17, 0.14, 
  2.59924}, {0.18, 0.14, 2.60161}, {0.19, 0.14, 2.5986}, {0.2, 0.14, 
  2.59709}, {0.21, 0.14, 2.59361}, {0.22, 0.14, 2.6034}, {0.23, 0.14, 
  2.60093}, {0.24, 0.14, 2.60235}, {0.25, 0.14, 2.59364}, {0.26, 0.14,
   2.59839}, {0.27, 0.14, 2.60632}, {0.28, 0.14, 2.59811}, {0.29, 
  0.14, 2.59455}, {0.3, 0.14, 2.59189}, {0.31, 0.14, 2.60737}, {0.32, 
  0.14, 2.60287}, {0.33, 0.14, 2.60053}, {0.34, 0.14, 2.59383}, {0.35,
   0.14, 2.60032}, {0.36, 0.14, 2.60113}, {0.37, 0.14, 
  2.60096}, {0.38, 0.14, 2.60532}, {0., 0.13, 2.59669}, {0.01, 0.13, 
  2.59326}, {0.02, 0.13, 2.59681}, {0.03, 0.13, 2.60031}, {0.04, 0.13,
   2.60124}, {0.05, 0.13, 2.59213}, {0.06, 0.13, 2.59756}, {0.07, 
  0.13, 2.59837}, {0.08, 0.13, 2.60215}, {0.09, 0.13, 2.59748}, {0.1, 
  0.13, 2.60116}, {0.11, 0.13, 2.59687}, {0.12, 0.13, 2.59615}, {0.13,
   0.13, 4.99208}, {0.14, 0.13, 2.59454}, {0.15, 0.13, 
  2.59712}, {0.16, 0.13, 2.60428}, {0.17, 0.13, 2.60043}, {0.18, 0.13,
   2.59995}, {0.19, 0.13, 2.60149}, {0.2, 0.13, 2.59992}, {0.21, 0.13,
   2.60634}, {0.22, 0.13, 2.60373}, {0.23, 0.13, 2.60056}, {0.24, 
  0.13, 2.59292}, {0.25, 0.13, 2.59537}, {0.26, 0.13, 2.60042}, {0.27,
   0.13, 2.59915}, {0.28, 0.13, 2.59918}, {0.29, 0.13, 2.60471}, {0.3,
   0.13, 2.60514}, {0.31, 0.13, 2.59247}, {0.32, 0.13, 
  2.60599}, {0.33, 0.13, 2.59984}, {0.34, 0.13, 2.59515}, {0.35, 0.13,
   2.60061}, {0.36, 0.13, 2.59956}, {0.37, 0.13, 2.60265}, {0.38, 
  0.13, 2.60408}, {0., 0.12, 2.59715}, {0.01, 0.12, 2.6028}, {0.02, 
  0.12, 2.61016}, {0.03, 0.12, 2.59965}, {0.04, 0.12, 2.59996}, {0.05,
   0.12, 2.59887}, {0.06, 0.12, 2.60171}, {0.07, 0.12, 
  2.60536}, {0.08, 0.12, 2.59956}, {0.09, 0.12, 2.59816}, {0.1, 0.12, 
  2.60429}, {0.11, 0.12, 2.59501}, {0.12, 0.12, 4.99442}, {0.13, 0.12,
   2.59679}, {0.14, 0.12, 2.59698}, {0.15, 0.12, 2.60692}, {0.16, 
  0.12, 2.6001}, {0.17, 0.12, 2.59958}, {0.18, 0.12, 2.59765}, {0.19, 
  0.12, 2.5987}, {0.2, 0.12, 2.59745}, {0.21, 0.12, 2.59767}, {0.22, 
  0.12, 2.59533}, {0.23, 0.12, 2.59378}, {0.24, 0.12, 2.59692}, {0.25,
   0.12, 2.6015}, {0.26, 0.12, 2.60057}, {0.27, 0.12, 2.59176}, {0.28,
   0.12, 2.60246}, {0.29, 0.12, 2.60687}, {0.3, 0.12, 2.60543}, {0.31,
   0.12, 2.59507}, {0.32, 0.12, 2.60331}, {0.33, 0.12, 
  2.60025}, {0.34, 0.12, 2.59965}, {0.35, 0.12, 2.60112}, {0.36, 0.12,
   2.60275}, {0.37, 0.12, 2.5938}, {0.38, 0.12, 2.59909}, {0., 0.11, 
  2.60253}, {0.01, 0.11, 2.59922}, {0.02, 0.11, 2.60249}, {0.03, 0.11,
   2.60457}, {0.04, 0.11, 2.60017}, {0.05, 0.11, 2.60275}, {0.06, 
  0.11, 2.60099}, {0.07, 0.11, 2.59675}, {0.08, 0.11, 2.59502}, {0.09,
   0.11, 2.59923}, {0.1, 0.11, 2.5963}, {0.11, 0.11, 4.99159}, {0.12, 
  0.11, 2.60084}, {0.13, 0.11, 2.59672}, {0.14, 0.11, 2.60424}, {0.15,
   0.11, 2.60859}, {0.16, 0.11, 2.60103}, {0.17, 0.11, 
  2.60735}, {0.18, 0.11, 2.5921}, {0.19, 0.11, 2.59926}, {0.2, 0.11, 
  2.60643}, {0.21, 0.11, 2.59665}, {0.22, 0.11, 2.60457}, {0.23, 0.11,
   2.59587}, {0.24, 0.11, 2.6036}, {0.25, 0.11, 2.59566}, {0.26, 0.11,
   2.60797}, {0.27, 0.11, 2.60034}, {0.28, 0.11, 2.5993}, {0.29, 0.11,
   2.59375}, {0.3, 0.11, 2.5985}, {0.31, 0.11, 2.60597}, {0.32, 0.11, 
  2.59958}, {0.33, 0.11, 2.59992}, {0.34, 0.11, 2.59645}, {0.35, 0.11,
   2.60102}, {0.36, 0.11, 2.60078}, {0.37, 0.11, 2.59701}, {0.38, 
  0.11, 2.59309}, {0., 0.1, 2.60234}, {0.01, 0.1, 2.605}, {0.02, 0.1, 
  2.59346}, {0.03, 0.1, 2.60538}, {0.04, 0.1, 2.6012}, {0.05, 0.1, 
  2.59611}, {0.06, 0.1, 2.6011}, {0.07, 0.1, 2.59662}, {0.08, 0.1, 
  2.59626}, {0.09, 0.1, 2.5955}, {0.1, 0.1, 4.981}, {0.11, 0.1, 
  2.59819}, {0.12, 0.1, 2.60239}, {0.13, 0.1, 2.60124}, {0.14, 0.1, 
  2.59551}, {0.15, 0.1, 2.60206}, {0.16, 0.1, 2.60306}, {0.17, 0.1, 
  2.60284}, {0.18, 0.1, 2.60786}, {0.19, 0.1, 2.60337}, {0.2, 0.1, 
  2.60415}, {0.21, 0.1, 2.59786}, {0.22, 0.1, 2.60247}, {0.23, 0.1, 
  2.60604}, {0.24, 0.1, 2.59826}, {0.25, 0.1, 2.59931}, {0.26, 0.1, 
  2.5969}, {0.27, 0.1, 2.59827}, {0.28, 0.1, 2.59902}, {0.29, 0.1, 
  2.59347}, {0.3, 0.1, 2.60377}, {0.31, 0.1, 2.60566}, {0.32, 0.1, 
  2.59767}, {0.33, 0.1, 2.60145}, {0.34, 0.1, 2.59943}, {0.35, 0.1, 
  2.60034}, {0.36, 0.1, 2.59878}, {0.37, 0.1, 2.5989}, {0.38, 0.1, 
  2.60168}, {0., 0.09, 2.60422}, {0.01, 0.09, 2.6097}, {0.02, 0.09, 
  2.59748}, {0.03, 0.09, 2.60017}, {0.04, 0.09, 2.59623}, {0.05, 0.09,
   2.59588}, {0.06, 0.09, 2.59091}, {0.07, 0.09, 2.60339}, {0.08, 
  0.09, 2.60147}, {0.09, 0.09, 5.00277}, {0.1, 0.09, 2.59198}, {0.11, 
  0.09, 2.59876}, {0.12, 0.09, 2.59655}, {0.13, 0.09, 2.59954}, {0.14,
   0.09, 2.602}, {0.15, 0.09, 2.60134}, {0.16, 0.09, 2.6036}, {0.17, 
  0.09, 2.59839}, {0.18, 0.09, 2.59434}, {0.19, 0.09, 2.60018}, {0.2, 
  0.09, 2.60286}, {0.21, 0.09, 2.59936}, {0.22, 0.09, 2.60396}, {0.23,
   0.09, 2.59643}, {0.24, 0.09, 2.60096}, {0.25, 0.09, 
  2.59818}, {0.26, 0.09, 2.59541}, {0.27, 0.09, 2.60234}, {0.28, 0.09,
   2.60143}, {0.29, 0.09, 2.59936}, {0.3, 0.09, 2.60079}, {0.31, 0.09,
   2.60063}, {0.32, 0.09, 2.59998}, {0.33, 0.09, 2.59996}, {0.34, 
  0.09, 2.59454}, {0.35, 0.09, 2.59597}, {0.36, 0.09, 2.60598}, {0.37,
   0.09, 2.58987}, {0.38, 0.09, 2.60077}, {0., 0.08, 2.60454}, {0.01, 
  0.08, 2.59343}, {0.02, 0.08, 2.604}, {0.03, 0.08, 2.60773}, {0.04, 
  0.08, 2.60157}, {0.05, 0.08, 2.59642}, {0.06, 0.08, 2.59923}, {0.07,
   0.08, 2.60035}, {0.08, 0.08, 5.00247}, {0.09, 0.08, 2.59571}, {0.1,
   0.08, 2.60259}, {0.11, 0.08, 2.60141}, {0.12, 0.08, 
  2.60196}, {0.13, 0.08, 2.59526}, {0.14, 0.08, 2.59722}, {0.15, 0.08,
   2.59713}, {0.16, 0.08, 2.59252}, {0.17, 0.08, 2.59832}, {0.18, 
  0.08, 2.60784}, {0.19, 0.08, 2.60348}, {0.2, 0.08, 2.59942}, {0.21, 
  0.08, 2.60117}, {0.22, 0.08, 2.60569}, {0.23, 0.08, 2.59578}, {0.24,
   0.08, 2.60078}, {0.25, 0.08, 2.59662}, {0.26, 0.08, 2.6005}, {0.27,
   0.08, 2.59993}, {0.28, 0.08, 2.60029}, {0.29, 0.08, 2.59546}, {0.3,
   0.08, 2.60548}, {0.31, 0.08, 2.60209}, {0.32, 0.08, 2.598}, {0.33, 
  0.08, 2.59758}, {0.34, 0.08, 2.5968}, {0.35, 0.08, 2.59345}, {0.36, 
  0.08, 2.5971}, {0.37, 0.08, 2.59671}, {0.38, 0.08, 2.60128}, {0., 
  0.07, 2.59762}, {0.01, 0.07, 2.60606}, {0.02, 0.07, 2.60334}, {0.03,
   0.07, 2.60751}, {0.04, 0.07, 2.60467}, {0.05, 0.07, 
  2.60254}, {0.06, 0.07, 2.59432}, {0.07, 0.07, 5.01209}, {0.08, 0.07,
   2.60207}, {0.09, 0.07, 2.59842}, {0.1, 0.07, 2.59311}, {0.11, 0.07,
   2.59581}, {0.12, 0.07, 2.59677}, {0.13, 0.07, 2.60218}, {0.14, 
  0.07, 2.59301}, {0.15, 0.07, 2.59883}, {0.16, 0.07, 2.5948}, {0.17, 
  0.07, 2.60164}, {0.18, 0.07, 2.59988}, {0.19, 0.07, 2.60142}, {0.2, 
  0.07, 2.60658}, {0.21, 0.07, 2.59602}, {0.22, 0.07, 2.60091}, {0.23,
   0.07, 2.6035}, {0.24, 0.07, 2.60478}, {0.25, 0.07, 2.60137}, {0.26,
   0.07, 2.6028}, {0.27, 0.07, 2.59658}, {0.28, 0.07, 2.60647}, {0.29,
   0.07, 2.59931}, {0.3, 0.07, 2.6}, {0.31, 0.07, 2.60511}, {0.32, 
  0.07, 2.60246}, {0.33, 0.07, 2.5956}, {0.34, 0.07, 2.5959}, {0.35, 
  0.07, 2.59782}, {0.36, 0.07, 2.59205}, {0.37, 0.07, 2.60238}, {0.38,
   0.07, 2.59602}, {0., 0.06, 2.60206}, {0.01, 0.06, 2.60069}, {0.02, 
  0.06, 2.58882}, {0.03, 0.06, 2.60324}, {0.04, 0.06, 2.5959}, {0.05, 
  0.06, 2.59754}, {0.06, 0.06, 4.99665}, {0.07, 0.06, 2.58979}, {0.08,
   0.06, 2.60281}, {0.09, 0.06, 2.5965}, {0.1, 0.06, 2.60235}, {0.11, 
  0.06, 2.59606}, {0.12, 0.06, 2.59566}, {0.13, 0.06, 2.60373}, {0.14,
   0.06, 2.59403}, {0.15, 0.06, 2.60043}, {0.16, 0.06, 
  2.60198}, {0.17, 0.06, 2.60317}, {0.18, 0.06, 2.60337}, {0.19, 0.06,
   2.59607}, {0.2, 0.06, 2.60456}, {0.21, 0.06, 2.59839}, {0.22, 0.06,
   2.59881}, {0.23, 0.06, 2.59454}, {0.24, 0.06, 2.59865}, {0.25, 
  0.06, 2.60408}, {0.26, 0.06, 2.6028}, {0.27, 0.06, 2.59744}, {0.28, 
  0.06, 2.59866}, {0.29, 0.06, 2.60286}, {0.3, 0.06, 2.60056}, {0.31, 
  0.06, 2.5916}, {0.32, 0.06, 2.60274}, {0.33, 0.06, 2.59902}, {0.34, 
  0.06, 2.59901}, {0.35, 0.06, 2.5999}, {0.36, 0.06, 2.60465}, {0.37, 
  0.06, 2.59873}, {0.38, 0.06, 2.60154}, {0., 0.05, 2.59743}, {0.01, 
  0.05, 2.59844}, {0.02, 0.05, 2.60088}, {0.03, 0.05, 2.59786}, {0.04,
   0.05, 2.59751}, {0.05, 0.05, 4.97879}, {0.06, 0.05, 
  2.59943}, {0.07, 0.05, 2.60136}, {0.08, 0.05, 2.59901}, {0.09, 0.05,
   2.59863}, {0.1, 0.05, 2.60378}, {0.11, 0.05, 2.59779}, {0.12, 0.05,
   2.60026}, {0.13, 0.05, 2.6052}, {0.14, 0.05, 2.59919}, {0.15, 0.05,
   2.60533}, {0.16, 0.05, 2.59944}, {0.17, 0.05, 2.60883}, {0.18, 
  0.05, 2.60031}, {0.19, 0.05, 2.60691}, {0.2, 0.05, 2.60038}, {0.21, 
  0.05, 2.60213}, {0.22, 0.05, 2.5952}, {0.23, 0.05, 2.60054}, {0.24, 
  0.05, 2.60246}, {0.25, 0.05, 2.59675}, {0.26, 0.05, 2.60414}, {0.27,
   0.05, 2.59794}, {0.28, 0.05, 2.59837}, {0.29, 0.05, 2.6}, {0.3, 
  0.05, 2.60652}, {0.31, 0.05, 2.59239}, {0.32, 0.05, 2.60335}, {0.33,
   0.05, 2.6}, {0.34, 0.05, 2.60034}, {0.35, 0.05, 2.59956}, {0.36, 
  0.05, 2.60721}, {0.37, 0.05, 2.59758}, {0.38, 0.05, 2.6016}, {0., 
  0.04, 2.60465}, {0.01, 0.04, 2.60495}, {0.02, 0.04, 2.59952}, {0.03,
   0.04, 2.59955}, {0.04, 0.04, 4.984}, {0.05, 0.04, 2.5988}, {0.06, 
  0.04, 2.59916}, {0.07, 0.04, 2.60799}, {0.08, 0.04, 2.59757}, {0.09,
   0.04, 2.59975}, {0.1, 0.04, 2.61261}, {0.11, 0.04, 2.59937}, {0.12,
   0.04, 2.60045}, {0.13, 0.04, 2.60209}, {0.14, 0.04, 
  2.59692}, {0.15, 0.04, 2.6082}, {0.16, 0.04, 2.59739}, {0.17, 0.04, 
  2.59741}, {0.18, 0.04, 2.60046}, {0.19, 0.04, 2.60816}, {0.2, 0.04, 
  2.60221}, {0.21, 0.04, 2.6019}, {0.22, 0.04, 2.60169}, {0.23, 0.04, 
  2.59754}, {0.24, 0.04, 2.60166}, {0.25, 0.04, 2.60272}, {0.26, 0.04,
   2.60141}, {0.27, 0.04, 2.60263}, {0.28, 0.04, 2.60263}, {0.29, 
  0.04, 2.60659}, {0.3, 0.04, 2.59846}, {0.31, 0.04, 2.60073}, {0.32, 
  0.04, 2.59933}, {0.33, 0.04, 2.60104}, {0.34, 0.04, 2.60496}, {0.35,
   0.04, 2.60628}, {0.36, 0.04, 2.60198}, {0.37, 0.04, 
  2.59436}, {0.38, 0.04, 2.59686}, {0., 0.03, 2.59903}, {0.01, 0.03, 
  2.5957}, {0.02, 0.03, 2.60352}, {0.03, 0.03, 4.99809}, {0.04, 0.03, 
  2.60661}, {0.05, 0.03, 2.60064}, {0.06, 0.03, 2.59765}, {0.07, 0.03,
   2.60583}, {0.08, 0.03, 2.60215}, {0.09, 0.03, 2.60325}, {0.1, 0.03,
   2.60021}, {0.11, 0.03, 2.59892}, {0.12, 0.03, 2.5999}, {0.13, 0.03,
   2.60293}, {0.14, 0.03, 2.59828}, {0.15, 0.03, 2.59338}, {0.16, 
  0.03, 2.60497}, {0.17, 0.03, 2.59519}, {0.18, 0.03, 2.59876}, {0.19,
   0.03, 2.60352}, {0.2, 0.03, 2.60329}, {0.21, 0.03, 2.60325}, {0.22,
   0.03, 2.59847}, {0.23, 0.03, 2.60344}, {0.24, 0.03, 
  2.59894}, {0.25, 0.03, 2.601}, {0.26, 0.03, 2.60404}, {0.27, 0.03, 
  2.5972}, {0.28, 0.03, 2.59132}, {0.29, 0.03, 2.60908}, {0.3, 0.03, 
  2.59935}, {0.31, 0.03, 2.60519}, {0.32, 0.03, 2.60766}, {0.33, 0.03,
   2.59998}, {0.34, 0.03, 2.59395}, {0.35, 0.03, 2.60317}, {0.36, 
  0.03, 2.60237}, {0.37, 0.03, 2.59888}, {0.38, 0.03, 2.60067}, {0., 
  0.02, 2.60092}, {0.01, 0.02, 2.59624}, {0.02, 0.02, 5.01027}, {0.03,
   0.02, 2.60332}, {0.04, 0.02, 2.60601}, {0.05, 0.02, 
  2.59942}, {0.06, 0.02, 2.60574}, {0.07, 0.02, 2.60309}, {0.08, 0.02,
   2.59692}, {0.09, 0.02, 2.59907}, {0.1, 0.02, 2.60545}, {0.11, 0.02,
   2.60083}, {0.12, 0.02, 2.59578}, {0.13, 0.02, 2.60028}, {0.14, 
  0.02, 2.60805}, {0.15, 0.02, 2.59373}, {0.16, 0.02, 2.59888}, {0.17,
   0.02, 2.59651}, {0.18, 0.02, 2.59766}, {0.19, 0.02, 2.60307}, {0.2,
   0.02, 2.60386}, {0.21, 0.02, 2.59306}, {0.22, 0.02, 
  2.59973}, {0.23, 0.02, 2.59884}, {0.24, 0.02, 2.60098}, {0.25, 0.02,
   2.60137}, {0.26, 0.02, 2.59616}, {0.27, 0.02, 2.59954}, {0.28, 
  0.02, 2.59453}, {0.29, 0.02, 2.60362}, {0.3, 0.02, 2.59612}, {0.31, 
  0.02, 2.5967}, {0.32, 0.02, 2.6007}, {0.33, 0.02, 2.60012}, {0.34, 
  0.02, 2.59326}, {0.35, 0.02, 2.60113}, {0.36, 0.02, 2.60077}, {0.37,
   0.02, 2.5953}, {0.38, 0.02, 2.60467}, {0., 0.01, 2.60739}, {0.01, 
  0.01, 4.98554}, {0.02, 0.01, 2.60059}, {0.03, 0.01, 2.59344}, {0.04,
   0.01, 2.59668}, {0.05, 0.01, 2.60086}, {0.06, 0.01, 
  2.59397}, {0.07, 0.01, 2.60333}, {0.08, 0.01, 2.59433}, {0.09, 0.01,
   2.60627}, {0.1, 0.01, 2.59895}, {0.11, 0.01, 2.59993}, {0.12, 0.01,
   2.60467}, {0.13, 0.01, 2.60401}, {0.14, 0.01, 2.59857}, {0.15, 
  0.01, 2.59374}, {0.16, 0.01, 2.60479}, {0.17, 0.01, 2.5926}, {0.18, 
  0.01, 2.59808}, {0.19, 0.01, 2.60449}, {0.2, 0.01, 2.60163}, {0.21, 
  0.01, 2.5926}, {0.22, 0.01, 2.6003}, {0.23, 0.01, 2.60097}, {0.24, 
  0.01, 2.59198}, {0.25, 0.01, 2.6036}, {0.26, 0.01, 2.59881}, {0.27, 
  0.01, 2.59837}, {0.28, 0.01, 2.59488}, {0.29, 0.01, 2.60285}, {0.3, 
  0.01, 2.59925}, {0.31, 0.01, 2.59813}, {0.32, 0.01, 2.60109}, {0.33,
   0.01, 2.59971}, {0.34, 0.01, 2.59679}, {0.35, 0.01, 
  2.60145}, {0.36, 0.01, 2.59759}, {0.37, 0.01, 2.59456}, {0.38, 0.01,
   2.59703}, {0., 0., 5.0081}, {0.01, 0., 2.59807}, {0.02, 0., 
  2.60425}, {0.03, 0., 2.60712}, {0.04, 0., 2.60097}, {0.05, 0., 
  2.59795}, {0.06, 0., 2.59988}, {0.07, 0., 2.60281}, {0.08, 0., 
  2.60758}, {0.09, 0., 2.59954}, {0.1, 0., 2.5963}, {0.11, 0., 
  2.60507}, {0.12, 0., 2.60281}, {0.13, 0., 2.59657}, {0.14, 0., 
  2.60099}, {0.15, 0., 2.59808}, {0.16, 0., 2.59395}, {0.17, 0., 
  2.59848}, {0.18, 0., 2.607}, {0.19, 0., 2.60423}, {0.2, 0., 
  2.60108}, {0.21, 0., 2.60266}, {0.22, 0., 2.60086}, {0.23, 0., 
  2.59726}, {0.24, 0., 2.5975}, {0.25, 0., 2.59612}, {0.26, 0., 
  2.59767}, {0.27, 0., 2.59798}, {0.28, 0., 2.60014}, {0.29, 0., 
  2.60552}, {0.3, 0., 2.60041}, {0.31, 0., 2.6013}, {0.32, 0., 
  2.59261}, {0.33, 0., 2.60142}, {0.34, 0., 2.60225}, {0.35, 0., 
  2.60149}, {0.36, 0., 2.60377}, {0.37, 0., 2.60042}, {0.38, 0., 
  2.59942}}```
````

Answer (score 1):

I think your data is too "coarse" to show the detail in your desired display.  In addition, the vast majority of values are right at 2.6 (ranging only between 2.58599 to 2.61434).  Then there are just a few values around 5.0 (ranging only between 4.97879 to 5.01542).  So there's a huge gap between the two sets of numbers.  Here's a plot of the grid with the values around 5.0 shown in red:

```
data2 = Select[data, #[[3]] > 3 &];
Show[ListPlot[data[[All, {1, 2}]], Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1],
 ListPlot[data2[[All, {1, 2}]], PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image: Grid of values]

If one subtracts 0.23 from the numbers around 5, then some semblance of what you want appears:

```
data2 = data;
data2[[All, 3]] = If[# > 2.7, # - 2.3, #] & /@ data[[All, 3]];
Show[ListContourPlot[data2, PlotRange -> All, Contours -> 100, 
  ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", ColorFunctionScaling -> True, 
  ContourStyle -> None, ImageSize -> Large],
 ListPlot[data[[All, {1, 2}]], PlotStyle -> Black]]
```

[image: Contour plot]

Comment: I guess i can try using log scale so the variations can be appreciated

Comment: I don't think a log scale will help.  (I did try that and it doesn't help.)  The "ridge" of high values is simply based on a small number of isolated points (i.e., too coarse a grid near the ridge).  Now if you had a theoretical model that would describe the transition from the ridge to the nearby "flatland", then you might have something.